# Can i get Javascript Loaded HTML using C# WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, html

I have a site where the content is loaded via javascript and is triggered when you scroll down or a javascript button being created at the bottom.

I have tried the scrolltoview and set it to false and then getting the documenttext but still no luck.

Any idea on how to approach this?